# Docker container built on intel and to run on ARM

Tags: docker, containers, intel, docker-machine

I have a Docker container created on intel pc but I have the necessity to run on ARM cpu.

Is there a system in order to convert this container or to add a layer in order to bypass this problem?

Comment: You might want to read this: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/ and related forum post: https://forums.docker.com/t/run-x86-intel-and-arm-based-images-on-apple-silicon-m1-macs/117123.

Comment: Thanks, have you a complete example. I have some container  that I can see by `docker container ls -a `but I don't understand how to use buildx on it